# Eclipse - CDT Content Assist extremely slow

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I just installed eclipse-cdt 3.2.2 on Linux (Mint). The content assist feature which pops up when you do a "." or "->" on a struct or struct pointer, is extremely slow and freezes the entire IDE for around 10-20 seconds.

This I feel, is because it searches through the entire include directory /usr/include that comes by default for any C project that you create.

How can this issue be solved?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have [bug 196203](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse-cdt/+bug/196203) which points to [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=201378) with some settings to perform.
It includes:

- how to make Eclipse actually use Sun's Java solving the "Eclipse is horribly slow" problem caused by bug 45347.
- raising the default heap size.